# Alter html output of a term reference form field

Tags: theming, entities

On my node edit form a term reference field is rendered with the following html output:

```
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-trainingstype-und">
  <input type="radio" id="edit-field-trainingstype-und-12" name="field_trainingstype[und]" value="12" class="form-radio">  
  <label class="option" for="edit-field-trainingstype-und-12">External </label>
</div>
```

As you can see the value attribute is set to 12 which is the term id of that particular item. Now I would like to replace 12 with the term name, **External**.

So it would look like:

```
<div class="form-item form-type-radio form-item-field-trainingstype-und">
  <input type="radio" id="edit-field-trainingstype-und-12" name="field_trainingstype[und]" value="External" class="form-radio">  
  <label class="option" for="edit-field-trainingstype-und-12">External </label>
</div>
```

I am unsure which function to use to target this particular field.
I was looking at [theme_checkbox()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_checkbox/7) and [theme_form_element()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/theme_form_element/7) but I am uncertain how to proceed and if these are the right functions for the job.

**UPDATE:**
So I would like to show another field based on the option chosen for the field_trainingstype. In a hook_form_alter I am now doing this:

```
$form['field_organisaton']['#states'] = array(
  'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="field_trainingstype[und]"]' => array('value' => '12'),
  ),
);
```

But I would like to trigger this by term name External because the term id might differ per environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doing it that way round will cause problems with the form submission; the value for a term reference field needs to be an integer and throwing a string at it will undoubtedly upset things. You could massage values back into place in a validate function but it seems a bit...messy.

The alternative would be to load the taxonomy term up in the form, so you can use the ID from there:

```
$terms = taxonomy_get_term_by_name('External', 'vocab_machine_name');
$term = array_shift($terms);
$form['field_organisaton']['#states'] = array(
  'visible' => array(
    ':input[name="field_trainingstype[und]"]' => array('value' => $term->tid),
  ),
);
```

That should make it reusable across different environments (provided the vocab only has one term with the name "External").

Comment: Arghh, ofcourse. Was thinking the other way around. Thanks.

Comment: taxonomy_get_term_by_name() returns an array of term objects, indexed by tid. So in my case, where I am sure  I have only one term with the name External I could and have to do this $term = reset(taxonomy_get_term_by_name('Extern', 'trainingstypen'));

Comment: So it does @undersound, sorry about that